# Avoid creating empty cells in grid CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Below is more or less what I want but its not perfect: there are gaps in the grid:

[Grid with gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSo7I.png)

Is there a way to avoid these gaps? Could this be done with pure CSS? Please find my HTML and CSS below:

HTML:

```
<div class="image-canvas">
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    <div class='placeholder'></div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(0, 80px));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 0));
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}

.placeholder:nth-child(3n+2) {
    grid-row: span 2;
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so for anyone wondering in the future, you need to add `grid-auto-flow: dense;` to the grid container. From:

```
.image-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(0, 80px));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 0));
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

to:

```
.image-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(0, 80px));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 0));
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense; 
}
```